# How to play an audio file in background in ios 6?

Tags: iphone, audio, ios6

I tried so many codes which i searched here .can i have any running code for audio.I want play a very short audio file in background thats it.

Comment: Did you put App Plays Audio in Required Background Mode of your Info.plist? Where are you stucked?

Comment: wait let me check this

Comment: NSURL* musicFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource"winner" ofType"mp3"]];
                                                                                                                            player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];
                                                              [player setVolume:1.0];
                                                               [player prepareToPlay];
                                                              [player play];

Comment: You still need to set the background mode if you want to play when your app is in the background.

Comment: agreed with @TomHarrington. You need to set mode for your background task. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple just double press the home button and you will get a small bar in the bottom of the screen just slide your finger to the right and there you get the audio controls just tap on the play button and your music will start.